# GridSearchCV Best Score Way off Base

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest

I am training on some data via gridsearch and I noticed that the best score is coming out to be way off base from what itd be for the test set:

```
custom_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, greater_is_better=True,  pos_label=1)

rf_params = {
    'max_depth': [20,50,100,150],
    'min_samples_split' : [10, 20, 50, 100],
}

rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)

rf_grid = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid = rf_params, cv = 5, scoring = custom_scorer)

rf_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print( "Best Score: {}".format(rf_grid.best_score_) )
>> Best Score: 0.9616742738181994
```

When I run on the test set its looking like this:

```
y_preds = rf_grid.predict(X_test)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_preds))

                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.93      1.00      0.96      2308
           1       0.88      0.07      0.13       192

    accuracy                           0.93      2500
   macro avg       0.90      0.54      0.55      2500
weighted avg       0.92      0.93      0.90      2500
```

As you can see the F1 score on the positive class is 0.13 which is very different from the `best_score_` on GridSearchCV. I know that they should be different because its different data sets but this is just confusing.

I tried a lot of variations on this testing including upsampling the minority class, enhancing/reducing the params. Not sure what else.

Comment: It could just be that the test set is not representative; how did you obtain the train/test split?  What is the score on the training set, `f1_score(y_train, rf_grid.predict(X_train))`?  (I think you should be able to just put `scoring='f1_score'` in the search, rather than defining the "custom" scorer.)

Comment: thanks. `f1_score(y_train, rf_grid.predict(X_train))` is giving me something in the 0.90 range. so definitely seems like the test set is not representative. im also wondering with 192 positive labels in my test set, it might be too little given high dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think, that you should reduce your depth to something like 20 at max (if you have 2 classes with ~3k samples), your RandomForest simply overfits your data.

Secondary, if you have such a massive class imbalance, you should deffinetely try specifying `class_weight` argument in `fit()` function (check sklearn's `compute_class_weight()` method).

Also, try a little bit wider parameters grid, such as `num_estimators`, `min_samples_leaf`, `class_weight`, `max_samples`.

Comment: I dont think this really gets at the core problem. I can and have tuned these hyperparameters to no end but they are always coming off as being very far off from the test set.

Comment: Try reducing num_estimators and think about your data quality